# Pushing newly created whole object to array with prototype function

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, prototype

I am trying to run a function on the construction of my objects which passes the whole object to a function, which then pushes it to an array.

I can pass one property at a time like this:

```
    function Item(title, description, price) {
    'use strict';
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.getPrice = function (price) {
        var pricestring = "£";
        pricestring = pricestring + price;
        return pricestring;
    };
    this.addToPage(this.title, this.description);
}
```

But I would like to be able to pass the whole object like this:

```
this.addToPage(this.Item);
```

however it always returns undefined.

My addToPage is function is like this:

```
Item.prototype.addToPage = function (item) {
    'use strict';
    constructedItems.push(item);
};
```

Is it actually possible to pass the whole object from inside the object? or is there another technique I could use?

Comment: `Is it actually possible to pass the whole object from inside the object?` Yes, in your case the whole object is simply `this`. But you don't want to pass it actually, because you only need a few properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `this`, which refers to the object being constructed.